# Struts Log Error - Method Invokation Failed

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

For a long time, ever since a recent change that allowed our users to keep their lost work in case of a system failure for our contact log form, we have had reports of a problem with one of our input forms.  When the user tries to enter a very basic contact log (No files, one option, a date to mark it, and the log itself), they are bounced out of our app.  Immediately afterwards, if they log in and try again, they can successfully submit the form.

We have been so far unable to duplicate this error on our test server, but we have narrowed down the error thrown when it happens.  In our log, it looks like this:

```
[5/23/13 13:18:47:837 EDT] 46b24806 PropertyUtils E org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils  Method invocation failed.
[5/23/13 13:18:47:853 EDT] 46b24806 PropertyUtils E org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils  TRAS0014I: The following exception was logged java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
```

It goes on for several lines, but the jist of the errors seem to indicate a Struts problem.  The method being utilized is a do method that writes to an SQL database, though the database itself doesn't seem to be the source of this problem.

Any sort of help or guidance would be appreciated.  We have thrown multiple theories across the table, but without being able to duplicate the problem, it's fairly difficult to find a solution.  Thank you in advance.

ONE ADDITIONAL NOTE: We are using Struts v. 1.2

Comment: I simply think that users should have access to the resources and once they are authenticated the process go.

Comment: It's impossible to help with the information provided. It looks like there's an issue in the form properties.